# Two JQuerys (Image Slider and Caption) only caption first image of list?

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I need your help. Can you tell me why this mix of a Slider and Caption JQuery only work together for the first image? The Slider works perfectly, but I only get a caption for the first image..."Flexslider" and "Capty" are used.

// Got it: Had to create a class for many Images with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('.classXYZ').capty();

        });
    </script>
```

And then give every image the class. Didnt know, I can give an image a class and they still stay in the slider class.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>xxx</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.capty.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.capty.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    controlsContainer: ".container",
    animation: "fade",
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    animationSpeed: 1500,
    controlNav: false,               
    directionNav: true,  
    nextText: "",
    prevText: "",
    })
  });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('#default').capty();

        });
    </script>



</head>

<body bgcolor="#1c1c1c">

<center>
<img src="header2.png">
<font color="white" face="Georgia" size="3">
    <table border="0">
        <td width="225px"><center><a href="architektur.html">Architektur</center></td></a>
        <td width="225px"><center><a href="natur.html">Natur</center></td></a>
        <td width="225px"><center><a href="portrait.html">Portrait</center></td></a>
        <td width="225px"><center><a href="divers.html">Divers</center></td></a>
    </table>
</font>
</center>

<div style="position:absolute; top:10%; left:50%"><div style="position: relative; left: -50%;"> 

<div class="flexslider" style="width:900px">
<ul class="slides">
    <li><img id="default" alt="Test" src="images/startupslides/01.jpg" style="width:900px" height="600px"></li>
    <li><img id="default" alt="Test" src="images/startupslides/02.png" style="width:900px" height="600px"></li>
    <li><img id="default" alt="Test" src="images/startupslides/03.jpg" style="width:900px" height="600px"></li>
    <li><img id="default" alt="Test" src="images/startupslides/04.png" style="width:900px" height="600px"></li>
    <li><img id="default" alt="Test" src="images/startupslides/05.jpg" style="width:900px" height="600px"></li>
    <li><img id="default" alt="Test" src="images/startupslides/06.png" style="width:900px" height="600px"></li>
    <li><img id="default" alt="Test" src="images/startupslides/07.jpg" style="width:900px" height="600px"></li>
    <li><img id="default" alt="Test" src="images/startupslides/08.jpg" style="width:900px" height="600px"></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
 * jQuery FlexSlider v2.2.0
 * http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
 *
 * Copyright 2012 WooThemes
 * Free to use under the GPLv2 license.
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * Contributing author: Tyler Smith (@mbmufffin)
 */


/* Browser Resets
*********************************/
.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

/* Icon Fonts
*********************************/
/* Font-face Icons */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontawesome-icon';
    src:url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src:url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {content: "\0020"; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;}
* html .slides {height: 1%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}

/* FlexSlider Default Theme
*********************************/
.flexslider { margin: 30px 0 60px; background: ; border: none; position: relative; _-webkit-border-radius: 4px; _-moz-border-radius: 4px; -o-border-radius: 4px; _border-radius: 4px; _-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); _-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); _box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); zoom: 1; }
.flex-viewport { max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; -o-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease; }
.loading .flex-viewport { max-height: 300px; }
.flexslider .slides { zoom: 1; }
.carousel li { margin-right: 5px; }

/* Direction Nav */
.flex-direction-nav {*height: 0;}
.flex-direction-nav a  { display: block; width: 40px; height: 40px; margin: -20px 0 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 10; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3); -webkit-transition: all .3s ease; -moz-transition: all .3s ease; transition: all .3s ease; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: -50px; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next { right: -50px; _text-align: right; }
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev { opacity: 0.7; left: 10px; }
.flexslider:hover .flex-next { opacity: 0.7; right: 10px; }
.flexslider:hover .flex-next:hover, .flexslider:hover .flex-prev:hover { opacity: 1; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled { opacity: 0!important; filter:alpha(opacity=0); cursor: default; }
.flex-direction-nav a:before  { font-family: "fontawesome-icon"; font-size: 30px; display: inline-block; content: '\f137';}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before  { content: '\f138'; }

/* Pause/Play */
.flex-pauseplay a { display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 10px; opacity: 0.8; z-index: 10; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; color: #000; }
.flex-pauseplay a:before  { font-family: "flexslider-icon"; font-size: 20px; display: inline-block; content: '\f004'; }
.flex-pauseplay a:hover  { opacity: 1; }
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before { content: '\f003'; }

/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-nav {width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: -40px; text-align: center;}
.flex-control-nav li {margin: 0 6px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;}
.flex-control-paging li a {width: 11px; height: 11px; display: block; background: #666; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -o-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
.flex-control-paging li a:hover { background: #333; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active { background: #000; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); cursor: default; }

.flex-control-thumbs {margin: 5px 0 0; position: static; overflow: hidden;}
.flex-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
.flex-control-thumbs img {width: 100%; display: block; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {opacity: 1; cursor: default;}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { opacity: 1; left: 10px;}
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { opacity: 1; right: 10px;}
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

CSS Caption:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

div.capty-caption {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font: bold 11px verdana;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #222;
}

div.capty-caption a {
    color: #318DAD;
    font: bold 11px verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.capty.css"/>
```

Probably these two CSS files are conflicting with eachother they have some id or class in common so they are manipulating one way or the other way. Try to implement it without one of those slider js and css files.